# How to manipulate the summation $\sum_{J=n+3}^{\infty} \frac{f(n,J)}{(J-n-2)!}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Is there some manipulation $g$ that can be applied to the sum
$$I(n) = \sum_{J=n+3}^{\infty} \frac{f(n,J)}{(J-n-2)!}$$

Such that we are left with
$$g(I(n)) = \sum_{J=n+3}^{\infty} \frac{f(n,J)}{(J-n)!}$$

edit: $f(n,J) = \frac{(-1)^{J+n} \zeta(J) (J-1)! 2^{n}}{2^{J} (2^{n} - 2)}$

Comment: What do we know about $f(n,J)$? Any link between $f(n,J+2)$ and $f(n,J)$?

Comment: $f(n,J) = \frac{(-1)^{J+n} \zeta (J) (J-1)! 2^{n}}{2^{J} (2^{n} -2)}$

Comment: @Riakm That should've already been in the question.

Comment: By the change of index $j=J-2$ one gets $$\sum_{J=n+3}^{\infty} \frac{f(n,J)}{(J-n-2)!}=\sum_{j=n+1}^{\infty} \frac{f(n,j+2)}{(j-n)!} $$ I don't know if this can help.

Answer (score 0):

Let 
\begin{eqnarray*}
K(n,x)= \sum_{J=n+3}^{\infty} \frac{f(n,J)}{(J-n)!} x^{J-n}
\end{eqnarray*}
Now differentiate twice with respect to $x$ and we have
\begin{eqnarray*}
K''(n,x)= \sum_{J=n+3}^{\infty} \frac{f(n,J)}{(J-n-2)!} x^{J-n-2}
\end{eqnarray*}
Now set $x=1$.

Comment: The main problem I see with this approach is that I do not know the closed form of $K''(n,x)$ only $K''(n,1)$, and thus I cannot integrate to find $K(n,1)$.

Comment: Is $\zeta(J)$ the Riemann zeta function ? by any chance ?

Comment: Yes $\zeta(J)$ is the Riemann Zeta function.